# Is there a downvote rate per tag statistic?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, statistics

I have a feeling that certain programmer communities are more prone to downvote than others.

Is there a statistic I can look at to verify this hypothesis?

For example, do Haskellers vote down more than Pythonistas?

Comment: Have a visit to the c++ shark tank ;)

Comment: c++ is my preferred. But there's a 2nd down vote now.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/169050/most-and-least-dangerous-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions

Comment: @Hans Oh, c++ doesn't even appear :/

Comment: [If the premise of your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337143/is-there-a-downvote-rate-per-tag-statistic#comment408904_337144) is *I want to know in which tags people downvote more so I can avoid them*, it is mistaken. Downvoting and upvoting are both part of how the community works, and they are **both** very important. A misguided upvote is just as harmful to the site as a misguided downvote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, c++ appears at position 22. You have to scroll down the result list.

Comment: @honk [Catch 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) actually? That's a nice one.

Comment: We can calculate this with the SQL API no?

Comment: @SeanReddy see [Hans Passant's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337143/is-there-a-downvote-rate-per-tag-statistic#comment408900_337143)

Comment: Can we have a query which only takes the last 1 or 2 years into account? That would give the current trend more accurately I guess.

Comment: @Codebender A good place to start might be [*Sudden change in voting proportion*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/30389), though the queries there do not distinguish between tags. (In any case, I think it is plausible that the trends in each tag should roughly follow the global trend unless there is a sudden demographic shift in a particular tag. This hypothesis, of course, would have to be verified.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The hypothesis can be (partly) verified with [this version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/567260/714950) of the query mentioned in [a comment by Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337143/is-there-a-downvote-rate-per-tag-statistic#comment408900_337143), which was adjusted to cover all tags with 25000+ questions. Here are the positions among the 189 included tags, as well as the answer downvote/upvote ratios, for the tags mentioned in this discussion :

- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) : 1st (4.84%)
- [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) : 40th (3.54%)
- [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) : 64th (3.24%)
- [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) : 94th (3.00%)
- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) : 116th (2.76%)
- [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) : 187th (1.33%)

Following user000001's suggestion, here is [the corresponding query for questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/567328/715053), as well as sample results for the same tags:

- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) : 4th (24.77%)
- [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) : 12th (20.84%)
- [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) : 17th (19.87%)
- [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) : 43rd (14.04%)
- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) : 74th (10.96%)
- [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) : 177th (3.80%)

Comment: Note that the query description only mentions answers, and not questions.

Comment: I find it very disappointing that `D/U` is greater than 1 for all tags

Comment: @UriGoren The values are percentual. For [tag:vba], for instance, there are three downvotes for every hundred upvotes.

Comment: @user000001 Assuming the query linked by Hans Passant is correct (and it looks like it is), only answers are included.

Comment: @duplode: Exactly. But the question asks for the ratio in general, not only for answers. The query should be forked to include both IMO.

Comment: @user000001 Indeed, the wrong assumption was mine. That would be a worthwhile addition.

Comment: I've updated the query (see http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/567266)

Comment: Now it shows potential reputation increase by tag

Comment: `(-2*downvote + 10*upvote) / (total votes)` , very interesting !

Comment: @user000001 Following your suggestion, I added data about questions. Questions and answers are different animals, so I believe it makes sense to look at the data for each case separately, rather than merging them into a single query.

Comment: results are likely skewed because there is no data on deleted posts (as far as I know SEDE [PostsWithDeleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/165773) doesn't have the information about votes down and up). And skew might be quite substantial - for example about 3/4 of 40,000 posts I reviewed in close queue are deleted, and many of them had votes down

Comment: the results do not show "dangerous tags for asking". Tags such as `if-statement`, `for-loop` being at the top indicate questions from complete beginners i.e., it is consistent with the unsurprising observation: "people new to programming ask worse questions"

Comment: All those upvotes in [tag:php] (in fact, in all of the web technologies) are upsetting. Those tags are steaming.

Comment: @gnat Indeed, though one might expect there is correlation between downvotes and deletions, in which case the results above would be at least a faint echo of the real situation.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I didn't bother with changing the tongue-in-cheek title of the original query. Ideally, tags such as [tag:if-statement] would be left out of the ranking; however, there seems to be no metadata about tags for doing that automatically via SEDE.

Answer (score -19):

> I have a feeling that certain programmer communities are more prone to down-vote than others.

That may be well true. Some tags have more engaged users than others. Though it's completely unclear what you want to deviate with such statistics. I don't see a goal.

Comment: When choosing a technical stack, the community is huge factor for me. I think that the down-vote rate is a measurement of a community's tolerance to questions.

Comment: @UriGoren You should expect an extremely low tolerance in all the major programming language tags.

Comment: Why ? some programming languages are designed for beginners (such as `basic`, `python`) and some languages are less inviting for beginners (such as `haskell`).... at least this is my prior assumption

Comment: @UriGoren How do you expect I can give you a concise answer for that? Check the [tag:brainfuck] or [tag:malbolge] tags to get some more insight.

Comment: Actually, I got the answer from Hans, it's a shame there are so few tags. It's interesting whether the `D/U` correlates with the level of proficiency

Comment: @UriGoren I still don't get what you're actually after.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ does it matter? The question is answerable with a SEDE query, as Hans already showed, and those questions are fine. What is done with the information obtained from it is up to any reader. That said: your answer doesn't address the question, have my down vote.

Comment: @rene THX, I was awaiting DV's for that answer. The information itself is pretty useless though. Let's say a XY problem.

Comment: Sure, and a warning is fine but it is not up to us to judge before hand. That will block change and I don't think that is a good thing.

Comment: @rene May be I'm thinking a bit too far ahead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, you are, glad you realized that on your own, have a cookie.

Comment: @rene But in general that turns out to be a good thing ;)

Comment: THX for the backup whoever gave that to the _crazy cat women_. :P

Comment: "deviate"? Do you mean "derive"?

Comment: `I think that the down-vote rate is a measurement of a community's tolerance to questions` that doesn't take into account at all that the quality of questions, and the quantity of low quality questions, will vary massively per tag. In some tags, it's just the experts answering each others questions; in others, it's everyone and their dog. I don't think you will learn anything useful from this statistic.

Comment: @PeterMortensen May be. But the outcome will be derailed most probably.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Did I state anything different?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Useful or not, the high D/U tags seem to correspond with my intuition of horrible, horrible tags.  In other words, a disproportionate amount of *upvotes* are a problem, and/or a good problem indicator, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: And perhaps it's useful to be able to say that [tag:regex] is only 3.38 horrible whilst [tag:php] at 4.84 is currently the prime suction device.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I assume he meant "divinate", as in tell fortune from tealeaves and such.